# Delphi XE3, Get name of current Tabsheet

Tags: delphi, printing

I have multiple page controls that have multiple tabsheets.  I have graphs on each tabsheet that the user can print. I want to have a "Print" button on my tool bar panel.  I want one "Print" button that prints the graph that is on the active tabsheet, I need a way to tell which tabsheet is active.  I know the name of the graph based on the name of the tabsheet.  That way I can tell the "Print" button which graph to print without putting a "Print" button on each tabsheet.

In pseudo code I want the following

if active tabsheet equals 'today' then print todaygraph ;

Comment: `if PageControl.ActivePage.Caption = 'today' then`

Answer (score 4):

Tabsheets are held together by a `TPageControl`. This has the property `ActivePage`, which indicates the currently active TabSheet, or `nil`. If it is not `nil`, you can get the name of the page (i.e. the tabsheet) using `MyPageControl.ActivePage.Caption`.

Examples are given in the Delphi online help, e.g. [this page](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ComCtrls_TPageControl_ActivePage.html)